# How to add new parameter to subclass of immutable type in a function chain?

Tags: python, inheritance, parameter-passing, immutability

I have an class inheriting from an immutable type which uses `__new__`.  How would I add a new parameter to one function and elegantly pass it to a second function, which I know is in the chain of execution?

```
class ImmutableClass(ImmutableType):
    def functionA(param1=None, param2=None):
        # Do some stuff
        stuff self.functionB(param2)
        # Do some more stuff
        return stuff

    def functionB(param2):
        # Do some stuff
        newObjects = [ImmutableClass() for x in range(len(param2))]
        stuff = self.functionC(newObjects)
        # Do some more stuff
        return stuff

    def functionC(param3=None):
        # Do some stuff
        return stuff

class SomeClass(ImmutableClass):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return ImmutableClass.__new__(SomeClass, *args, **kwargs)

    def functionA(self, newParameter=True):
        # How do I pass newParameter to functionC?
        return super(ImmutableClass, self).functionA(*args, **kwargs)

    def functionC(self, newParameter=True):
        # How do I get the parameter from functionA?
        if not newParameter:
            print 'Success!'
        return super(ImmutableClass, self).functionC(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know I can add **kwargs to all of `ImmutableClass`'s functions in the chain, but this felt a bit messy.  Callers to these functions could pass invalid arguments for quite some time before erroring out, or passing a flag to some unintended function.  I'm hoping there's some obvious solution I'm not seeing.

I know `ImmutableClass` has `functionA` call `functionB`, which then calls `functionC`.  However, the call in `functionB` is in the middle of the code, so I can't simply prepend/append the new call.  I can't use a member variable (as far as I know), because of `__new__` re-initializing it half way through the call.  I have access to `ImmutableClass`'s source, but I'd prefer to not alter it, as `ImmutableClass` should have no knowledge of `SomeClass`.  I've thought of using a global variable, but I'm afraid that could do unexpected things if section of `SomeClass` starts a second, call of functionA.

Comment: I don't understand the correlation between `functionA` and `functionC`

Comment: Why can't you use a member variable? Did you actually try it?

Comment: I did try a member variable, it's re-initalized anytime that `__new__` is called.  And `__new__` is called several times in the execution of functionA-C, which I have no control over.

Comment: I'm confused, your example code doesn't show `__new__` getting called at all. Is `functionC` not getting called on the same object as `functionA`?

Comment: Now that I think of it, that's correct.  functionC is not operating on the same object as functionA.  That's why a member variable doesn't work - not because it's immutable, but because it's a different object.

Comment: @Jordan: you meant `return super(SomeClass, self)` instead of `return super(ImmutableClass, self)`, right?